# How do I get /proc file to return an integer instead of character in a Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, driver

New to C and Kernel Programming - so wondering if you can advise what I need to change to get the correct output.

I have a kernel module, which will create /proc/test_file

When I use the cat command on /proc/test_file - I want it to return the integer value stored in a variable "my_number". but right now it is returning the ascii character * (ascii decimal for * is 42), not the integer I have stored in "my_number". I'm assuming I'm calling the function incorrectly, or passing the variable in incorrectly somehow. I don't really *get* C yet.

```
// Includes
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

// License
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

// Defines
#define TEST_FILE "test_file"

// Declarations & Variables
static int start_module(void);
static void exit_module(void);
static void create_proc_fs_file(void);
static void cleanup_proc_fs_file(void);
static struct proc_dir_entry *res;

static int my_number = 42;
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *pos);
static struct proc_ops test_fops = {
    .proc_read = read_proc
};

// Entry and Exit
module_init(start_module);
module_exit(exit_module);

// Code
static int start_module(void)
{
    pr_info("\n\nSTARTING PROC ENTRY CREATION\n\n");
    create_proc_fs_file();
    return 0;
}

static void exit_module(void)
{
    cleanup_proc_fs_file();
    pr_info("\n\nExiting Module. Bye Bye!\n\n");
}

static void create_proc_fs_file(void)
{   
    // Create /proc/test_file
    res = proc_create(TEST_FILE, 0666, NULL, &test_fops);
    if(!res){
        pr_err("\nFailed to create /proc/test_file\n\n");
    }else{
        pr_info("\nSuccessfully create /proc/test_file\n\n");
    }

}

static void cleanup_proc_fs_file(void)
{   
    pr_info("\nRemoving /proc/test_file subtree....\n\n");
    remove_proc_subtree(TEST_FILE, NULL);
}

static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *pos) 
{   
    size_t len = sizeof(my_number);
    pr_info("\nproc file read....\n\n");
    if (*pos >= len) {
        return 0;  // End of file
    }

    if (count > len - *pos) {
        count = len - *pos;
    }
    if(copy_to_user(buffer, &my_number + *pos, count)){
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    *pos += count;
    return count;
}
```

Expected Output:

`chris@dev:~$cat /proc/test_file`
`42`

Actual Output:
`chris@dev:~$cat /proc/test_file`
`*`

I'm guessing the problem is here, that i'm telling it that "42" is a char and it's converting it or something:

static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *file, ***char __user *buffer***, size_t count, loff_t *pos)

**Edit:**

Just to come back and add working code based on the answer from @Tsyvarev below. One of the benefits is that it bypasses the need for file_operations via proc_ops - and so it will work on older kernel releases now (if that's something you need...)

```
// Includes
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>

// License
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

// Defines
#define TEST_FILE "test_file"

// Declarations & Variables
static int start_module(void);
static void exit_module(void);
static void create_proc_fs_file(void);
static void cleanup_proc_fs_file(void);
static struct proc_dir_entry *res;

static int my_number = 42;
static int print_out(struct seq_file *m, void *v);

// Entry and Exit
module_init(start_module);
module_exit(exit_module);

// Code
static int start_module(void)
{
    pr_info("\n\nSTARTING PROC ENTRY CREATION\n\n");
    create_proc_fs_file();
    return 0;
}

static void exit_module(void)
{
    cleanup_proc_fs_file();
    pr_info("\n\nExiting Module. Bye Bye!\n\n");
}

static void create_proc_fs_file(void)
{   
    // Create /proc/test_file
    res = proc_create_single(TEST_FILE, 0666, NULL, &print_out);
    if(!res){
        pr_err("\nFailed to create /proc/test_file\n\n");
    }else{
        pr_info("\nSuccessfully create /proc/test_file\n\n");
    }
}

static void cleanup_proc_fs_file(void)
{   
    pr_info("\nRemoving /proc/test_file subtree....\n\n");
    remove_proc_subtree(TEST_FILE, NULL);
}

static int print_out(struct seq_file *m, void *v) 
{   
    seq_printf(m, "Count of Packets: %d\n", my_number);
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: If you want to display two characters`'4'` and `'2'`, your device needs to return two ASCII codes, one for each. Or don't use `cat` but a short python command that will read binary data from stdin and print it as it's decimal text representation. Depends on what exactly you are expecting your driver to do.

Comment: Use `snprintf()` with `%d`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. So the kind of end goal will be that my module will have other functions that populate the variable (a counter that keeps track of certain actions happening) - and I can check /proc/test_file from user space to see what the current count of the various actions were. There's lots of other /proc files which give out nice neat detailed values e.g. /proc/meminfo  - so once I know how to reliably output strings and integers then i'll be able to start building that functionality.

Comment: If you want the device file to "contain" text data, then you need to convert your data to text before copying to the user space. That is, define a local string, `snprintf` the number into it as suggested above, then copy it to the user space.

Comment: @EugeneSh. ah yeah, that does make sense. I will look at turning the data to text first. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seq_file` provides a convenient mechanism which allows to easily create a file, representing some information as a string. For procfs this mechanism is available e.g. via `proc_create_single` function:

```c
// Pointer to the created file, so it can be deleted in the exit function.
static struct proc_dir_entry *res;
// Number which will be represented by the file.
static int my_number = 42;

// Generates the content of the file
static int my_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    // Just "print" the value of the integer variable.
    // Tail '\n' is useful for pretty output when use 'cat' utility.
    seq_printf(m, "%d\n", my_number);
    return 0;
}

static int start_module(void)
{
    pr_info("\n\nSTARTING PROC ENTRY CREATION\n\n");
    // Create a file
    res = proc_create_single(TEST_FILE, 0666, NULL, &my_show);
    // ... check for errors

    return 0;
}
```

With that approach you just provide `show` function (in the example above it is named as `my_show`) which will be called whenever the file will be read. The purpose of that function is to **generate content**, which will be returned to the user.

There are several helpers for generate content in such function, and `seq_printf` is one of them. As you could guess from its name, this helper is very similar to `printf` function, but operates with a seq_file.

The `show` function is then passed to `proc_create_single` as a parameter.

---

The `seq_file` mechanism is described e.g. in the [kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/seq_file.html). That documentation describes only appliance of the mechanism to "standard" files, with `file_operations`. Adaptation of the mechanism to procfs files is represented by several functions in [include/linux/proc_fs.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h) header.

Comment: FWIW, this needs kernel version 4.18 or later (for `proc_create_single`). But then OP's original code required kernel version 5.6 or later (for `struct proc_ops`), so no problem!

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Yeah this is doing exactly what I need it to do. Thanks a million. I don't need to specify file_operations in this instance - which suits me better for what I'm trying to achieve.